# Scrolling of Embedded Twitter timeline is not smooth on iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter, uiwebview, safari, scroll

I created a Twitter widget on a dedicated Html file. I plugged it into an app by calling the specific URL.
When I call this URL in Safari mobile browser and when I access to this page in the app (throug a webview), I observe that the scrolling is not smooth at all!

I tried to call the same URL on an Android device and the scrolling in the browser was smooth.

Someone knows how to manage this issue on iPhone?

Thanks

Seb

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had a chance to test this yet, but adding this to your main CSS file should work. You may or may not have to identify what div it's nested in.

```
.timeline-Viewport {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```